# Change column header background DataGrid UWP

Tags: uwp, datagrid, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I'm currently looking at the UWP DataGrid from Nuget Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid `xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"` and I want to change a single column header background color I've tryed change header style but so far nothing has come out. Here is my example:

```
        <controls:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfGrips}">
        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>

            <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                Header="First header"
                Width="SizeToHeader"
                Binding="{Binding DirectionType}"
                FontSize="15"
                Foreground="White">
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="primitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#58622D" />
                    </Style>
                </controls:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </controls:DataGridTextColumn>

            <!-- Other columns -->
        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:DataGrid>
```

[image]

So how could I change headers cells background color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the DataGrid does not give a property for setting the background color of the `DataGridColumnHeader`.

Through the analysis of the [source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.xaml#L561), it can be seen that the `Background` property is not actually bound to `BackgroundRectangle.Fill`.

If you want to change this behavior, you may need more additional code to do this, that is, **rewrite the style of `DataGridColumnHeader`.**

However, because `DataGrid` uses a lot of custom resources, you need to create a resource dictionary to store these default resources before rewriting the style.

**DefaultDataGridResources.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApplication.Template">
    <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="InvalidBrush" Color="#FFFF00"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FillerGridLinesBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="ScrollBarsSeparatorBackground" ResourceKey="SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderForegroundBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="SystemAltHighColor"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundColor}"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderHoveredBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="SystemListLowColor"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderPressedBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="SystemListMediumColor"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderDraggedBackgroundBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderPointerOverBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderPressedBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="InvalidBrush" Color="#FFFF00"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FillerGridLinesBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="ScrollBarsSeparatorBackground" ResourceKey="SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderForegroundBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="SystemAltHighColor"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundColor}"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderHoveredBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="SystemListLowColor"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderPressedBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="SystemListMediumColor"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderDraggedBackgroundBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderPointerOverBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderPressedBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="InvalidBrush" Color="#C50500"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FillerGridLinesBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarsSeparatorBackground" Color="{StaticResource SystemChromeMediumColor}" Opacity="0.9"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderForegroundBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="SystemAltHighColor"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundColor}"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderHoveredBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="SystemListLowColor"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderPressedBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="SystemListMediumColor"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderDraggedBackgroundBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderPointerOverBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderPressedBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlGridLinesBaseMediumLowBrush" Color="{StaticResource SystemBaseMediumLowColor}" Opacity="0.4"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlRowGroupHeaderBackgroundMediumBrush" Color="{StaticResource SystemChromeMediumColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridCurrencyVisualPrimaryBrush" Color="Transparent"/>

    <x:String x:Key="SortIconAscending">&#xE74A;</x:String>
    <x:String x:Key="SortIconDescending">&#xE74B;</x:String>
    <x:String x:Key="RowGroupHeaderIconClosed">&#xE0E3;</x:String>
    <x:String x:Key="RowGroupHeaderIconOpened">&#xE0E5;</x:String>

    <x:String x:Key="ScrollBarsSeparatorExpandBeginTime">00:00:00.40</x:String>
    <x:String x:Key="ScrollBarsSeparatorExpandDuration">00:00:00.1</x:String>
    <x:String x:Key="ScrollBarsSeparatorContractBeginTime">00:00:02.00</x:String>
    <x:String x:Key="ScrollBarsSeparatorContractDelay">00:00:02</x:String>
    <x:String x:Key="ScrollBarsSeparatorContractDuration">00:00:00.1</x:String>
    <x:String x:Key="ScrollBarsSeparatorContractFinalKeyframe">00:00:02.1</x:String>
    <x:String x:Key="ScrollBarsSeparatorNoTouchDuration">00:00:00.5</x:String>

    <x:Double x:Key="ListAccentLowOpacity">0.6</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="ListAccentMediumOpacity">0.8</x:Double>

    <StaticResource x:Key="GridLinesBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlGridLinesBaseMediumLowBrush"/>

    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridDetailsPresenterBackgroundBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridFillerColumnGridLinesBrush" ResourceKey="FillerGridLinesBrush"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="SystemAccentColor"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedBackgroundOpacity" ResourceKey="ListAccentLowOpacity"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="SystemAccentColor"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredBackgroundOpacity" ResourceKey="ListAccentMediumOpacity"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedUnfocusedBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="SystemAccentColor"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedUnfocusedBackgroundOpacity" ResourceKey="ListAccentLowOpacity"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredUnfocusedBackgroundColor" ResourceKey="SystemAccentColor"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredUnfocusedBackgroundOpacity" ResourceKey="ListAccentMediumOpacity"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowHeaderForegroundBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowHeaderBackgroundBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowGroupHeaderBackgroundBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowGroupHeaderHoveredBackgroundBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlBackgroundListLowBrush"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowGroupHeaderPressedBackgroundBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlBackgroundListMediumBrush"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowGroupHeaderForegroundBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridRowInvalidBrush" ResourceKey="InvalidBrush"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridCellBackgroundBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlTransparentBrush"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridCellFocusVisualPrimaryBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlFocusVisualPrimaryBrush"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridCellFocusVisualSecondaryBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlFocusVisualSecondaryBrush"/>
    <StaticResource x:Key="DataGridCellInvalidBrush" ResourceKey="InvalidBrush"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Reference in App.xaml

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application
    x:Class="TestApplication.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApplication">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Template/DefaultDataGridResources"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

---

After completing the above preparations, you can modify the style of our `DataGridColumnHeader`

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="primitives:DataGridColumnHeader" x:Key="CustomColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource DataGridColumnHeaderForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="{ThemeResource GridLinesBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="32"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="primitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Grid x:Name="ColumnHeaderRoot">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource DataGridColumnHeaderHoveredBackgroundColor}"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource DataGridColumnHeaderPressedBackgroundColor}"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SortStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unsorted"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SortAscending">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SortDescending">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="SortIcon.Glyph" Value="{ThemeResource SortIconDescending}"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="32" Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                            <FontIcon Grid.Column="1" x:Name="SortIcon" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="{ThemeResource SortIconAscending}" FontSize="12"
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource DataGridColumnHeaderForegroundBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalSeparator" Grid.Column="1" Width="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}"/>

                        <Grid x:Name="FocusVisual" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualPrimary" Stroke="{ThemeResource DataGridCellFocusVisualPrimaryBrush}" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Transparent" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualSecondary" Stroke="{ThemeResource DataGridCellFocusVisualSecondaryBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Transparent" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

**Usage**

```xml
<controls:DataGridTextColumn 
    ...>
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="primitives:DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#58622D" />
        </Style>
    </controls:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
</controls:DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundColor` to `Page.Resources`.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundColor">Blue</SolidColorBrush>
</Page.Resources>
```

This will change the background color of the DataGrid column headers to `Blue`.

Comment: Amazing! This should be the answer. I added to my DataGrid.Resources instead of the Page (or root) Resources and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You can also just apply background to the whole grid and change the color of grid lines and cells.

but you have to override `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundColor" Color="Red"/>` by any color